# Android NDK internalDataPath - Writing to file

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm using **internalDataPath** within my **NativeActivity** which when accessed at runtime looks something like this:

```
"/data/data/app.name/files"
```

I then try writing to the file like so:

```
- fopen("/data/data/app.name/files/test.txt", "wb");
- fwrite(buffer, size, count, m_handle);
- fclose(m_handle);
```

In this case, the fopen will fail and won't open the file which realistically means the other functions don't get called, I experimented by looking at the file system and instead, tried the following path.

```
"/Android/data/app.name/files/test.txt"
```

This works, it creates the file and allows for the other functions to write and close the file.

My question is, how come **internalDataPath** starts with **/data/** instead of **/Android/**? Have I done something wrong in the setup of my application? Should I be calling a different function?

It's also worth mentioning that

```
externalDataPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app.name/files"
```

Which means that for this device (which doesn't have an external SD) it points to the correct INTERNAL files path.

Let me know if any of this is unclear or you require more information.

Thanks

Comment: what devices and version is this? I don't have the 'Android' location, just 'data' at the root and that's what's being returned by `internalDataPath` so `fopen` works fine for me in a similar example.

Comment: Device: Nexus 7 Tablet (2012)
Version: Android 5.1.1 (LMY47V)

It's my development device so it's seen a fair number of flashes and roots etc, so perhaps it's just gotten into some broken state...

My Galaxy S6 on Android 6 seems to have both the "Android" folder and the "data" folder within the "/storage/emulated/0" path.

Comment: I've tested it on Nexus 7 2013 with Android 6.0.1. I'm not sure what could cause the `internalDataPath` variable to point to an invalid path. Have you tried doing a factory reset yet?

Comment: I will probably try that, it's weird, I wonder if there's something I'm supposed to setup so that the OS will create those folders for me when the application is installed/launched? I'm guessing i'm not supposed to create them manually right?

Comment: Maybe I am just supposed to create the whole thing manually? Would make sense I guess.

Comment: I doubt that, you don't even have these permissions by default if I'm not mistaken. I do have a `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app.name/files` directory without creating it manually.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely have the /Android/data/ path without doing anything manually, however both my Nexus 7 and Galaxy S6 don't have a /data/data/ path for my app, I'm going to try mkdir but I think you're right, without rooting permissions will block it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118837/discussion-between-patrik-h-and-maddius).

Comment: I've looked into my code that uses the internal datapath. I use  
mkdir( internalDataPath, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR );
Don't remember why I wrote the line, but i guess it means that the folder isn't exist by default, so you should create it before using.

Answer (score 0):

I added mkdir() to ensure the entire internalDataPath tree is definitely created and it seems to have worked on my Nexus 7, I can see the files being created with ES File Explorer.

It also works on my Galaxy S6, however I can't actually see the files in the ES File Explorer, but it works because the file is loaded and read upon the next restart so I can only assume I can't see the file because this device is not rooted.

It's worth noting that between versions of Android, internalData path has changed location, for example:

Nexus 7 (5.1.1):
internalDataPath = /data/data/app.name/files

Galaxy S6 (6.0.1):
internalDataPath = /data/user/0/app.name/files

These paths are absolute, or at least relative to the highest view-able root directory in ES File Explorer.

Not sure if this will help anybody, the main part of the problem was probably my own lack of knowledge of the Android file system since there seems to be lots of similarly structured directories, it's easy to get lost down the wrong one.

Thanks to Patrik and Dave for spending time looking into it with me.

Comment: glad this is working for you. I'd still be interested to know what mechanism is usually responsible to create these directories as this seems to happen automatically at first execution in my test cases on both 4.2.2 and 6.01